# What is an "arc" spectrum ?

Tags: observational-astronomy, amateur-observing, spectroscopy, spectra

I sometimes hear about astronomers using an arc spectrum to calibrate observations. For example a "He-Ar arc spectrum". What is an "arc" in this context? I assume it's nothing got to do with angles (arcmin, arcsec, etc.).

Comment: @ConradTurner, you could add some more details and make an answer out of your comment !

Comment: @LocalFluff See Conrad's answer. The arc refers to a discharge lamp.

Answer (score 6):

An arc spectrum is one produced by a discharge lamp where the discharge is through ionised gas, in the case of He-Ar a mixture of Helium and Argon, which produces a predictable line emission spectrum.

They are often used to provide a [calibration spectrum for spectrometers](http://www.ing.iac.es/astronomy/observing/manuals/ps/tech_notes/tn070_1.pdf).

Comment: An electric arc, in air, between two *iron* electrodes, is also used as a source of reference emission lines...